# ASP.NET Group level login system

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on group level login system in asp.net and SQL server. This script works fine but how do implement group level security system if the user is admin should be directed to admin page and user should be redirected to users page

```
private bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_authenticateuser", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Login1.Password, "SHA1");
            SqlParameter parmusername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", Login1.UserName);
            SqlParameter parmpassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parmusername);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parmpassword);
            con.Open();
            int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            //it will get Only one row will be ExecuteScalar();
            return ReturnCode == 1;

        }
    }
```

If user is and password is correct here should be the trick

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AuthenticateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
        {
            Session["Username"] = Login1.UserName;
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
        else
            lab_status.Text = "Invalid User";
    }
}
```

Procedure to validate user with return code

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_authenticateuser]
@Username varchar(100),
@Password varchar(100)
as 
begin
    declare @count int 
    select @count = count(Username) from users 
    where Username=@UserName and pass=@Password

    if (@count=1)
    begin 
    select 1 as ReturnCode 
    end
    else
    begin 
    select -1 as ReturnCode 
    end
    end
GO
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users](
    [usid] [int] IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [pass] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Roles] [int] 
 constraint [pk_uid] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 );
```

The script works perfectly now but how to redirect user to admin page if he is admin something like

```
if(AuthenticateUser(userrole=='1'){
 response.redirect("admin.aspx");
}else{
response.redirect("users.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Remember that `where Username=@UserName and pass=@Password` may be case insensitive depending on collation used.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(RadioButton1.Checked)

        {

            if (txtUsername.Text == "admin" && txtPassword.Text == "admin")


                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            else
                //Response.Write("error");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Enter Currect Passward');", true);

        }



            else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            {


                string query = "SP_StudLogin";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query,con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text.ToString());  //for username 
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text.ToString()); //for password
                con.Open();
                //int usercount = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();// for taking single value

                int usercount = (Int32)com.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();



                if (usercount == 1)  // comparing users from table 
                {
                    Response.Redirect("DeafultStaff.aspx");  //for sucsseful login
                }
                else
                {

                    //lblmsg.Text = "Invalid User Name or Password";  //for invalid login

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Enter Currect Passward');", true);
                }

            }
```

Comment: (a) What are `RadioButton1` and `RadioButton2`? (b) how does this answer the question?